# How to get the URL of an image inside a canvas element with Selenium in Java, and how to use JavascriptExecutor?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, canvas

My specific goal is to get the image URL from a canvas container, here is what is did:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

Object imageURL = jse.executeScript("arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png');",canvas);
```

I'm getting a return value of null.

Then I've tried to do something more basic, like getting the width attribute of the canvas.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Object width= jse.executeScript("arguments[0].getAttribute('width');",canvas);
```

Again I'm getting null. The canvas `WebElement` is well identified by Selenium and it's "width" attribute is exists - I can retrieve it with `WebDriver`'s `getAttribute` method.

I guess I'm using it wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `return` keyword to your script.

PS: let me know if it's resolved, else we can try something else.

Comment: Thanks! It was the problem!
Do you know what is the right way to convert this string to an image in Java? The string starts like this: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...."

Comment: yes i know, you need three line of code : 
<br />
String base64ImageContent = RegExService.findFirst("data:image\\/.*;base64,([^)^\"]*)",url,false,1);

<br />
byte[] bytesOfImage = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64ImageContent);
<br />
Files.write(Paths.get(fileManagerService.getMediaPath(),checksum.getChecksumFile()), bytesOfImage);

Answer (score 3):

For your original code, you just need to add `return` to get a value back. You can also cast the `Object` return as string, if you want.

```
String imageURL = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png');", canvas);
System.out.println(imageURL);
```

For the width portion, you don't even need JSE.

```
WebElement canvas = driver.findElement(...);
System.out.println(canvas.getAttribute("width"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Object imageURL = jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png').substring(22);",canvas);
```

With this code you get the string of base64 Image